# Incorrect Calculations

Tags: python-3.4

Here is my first calculation that works fine

```
# Calculate time it takes projectile to reach its target
def calcTime(distance,velocity,radians):
    time = distance / (velocity * math.cos(radians))
    return time
finaltime = calcTime(distance,velocity,radians)
```

Then I get to my second calculation which I get errors. Where am I going wrong? I have gravity as a constant set to 32.17 above and I keep getting the error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'

```
# Calculate the distance the projectile is off the ground at the targets distance
def calcHeight(velocity,finaltime,radians,const_gravity):
    height = velocity * finaltime * (math.sin * radians) - ((const_gravity * finaltime**2)/2)
    return height
finalheight = calcHeight(velocity,finaltime,radians,const_gravity)
```

I have tried to change float(finaltime) and float(finalheight) but those are both incorrect. How do I solve this problem because I know it's close.Essentially I am trying to print out the [finalheight] variable

Answer (score 0):

Your math.sin isn't passed any parameters; do you mean math.sin( radians)?

Comment: Sometimes I feel the calculations are not always accurate so I place parenthesis around them to do specific calculations but I believe that worked just changing it from math.sin(radians)